# Xamarin.Forms - x:Reference 2nd level

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently working in a new ContentPage for my application and I have some controls with DataTemplates.

I would like to use a Command in my ContentPage's ViewModel in one of the DataTemplates, however I'm not sure how to do the right reference for this to work properly. Here's my XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="MaverickMobileOnline.ImagesListingPage"

    --MANY NAMESPACE REFERENCES--
    >


    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <c:ItemTappedEventArgsConverter x:Key="ItemTappedConverter" />
          <c:ItemAppearingEventArgsConverter x:Key="ItemAppearingConverter" />
          <c:BooleanNegationConverter x:Key="not" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout Spacing="0">
        <commonViews:MainCustomNavBar MinimumHeightRequest="120" />


        <controls:PullToRefreshLayout
          x:Name = "layout" 
          RefreshCommand="{Binding btn_reload_businesses_images_click}"    
          IsEnabled = "True"        
          IsRefreshing="{Binding Path=is_businesses_loading}" > 

          <ScrollView
            x:Name = "scrollView"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

               <templates:ItemsStack 
                    Padding="0" 
                    Margin="0,10,0,10"
                    x:Name="itmStack"
                    BackgroundColor="White"  
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=photos_list}">

                <templates:ItemsStack.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <artina:GridOptionsView 

                                Padding="10,0" 
                                ColumnSpacing="10" 
                                RowSpacing="10" 
                                VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                                HeightRequest="120"
                                ColumnCount="3"
                                RowCount="1"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}">

                                <artina:GridOptionsView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>

                                        <ContentView 
                                            xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                                            x:Class="MaverickMobileOnline.GalleryImageItemTemplate"
                                            xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
                                            xmlns:fftransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations">

                                            <ContentView.Content>
                                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                                                    FadeAnimationEnabled="true" 
                                                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"

                                                    LoadingPlaceholder="advertising_photo_placeholder.png"
                                                    Source="{Binding Path=image_medium}" />
                                            </ContentView.Content>

                                            <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                                    -- HERE! --

                                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference X}, Path=BindingContext.command_name}" 
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding image_medium}"
                                                />
                                            </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>

                                        </ContentView>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </artina:GridOptionsView.ItemTemplate>
                            </artina:GridOptionsView>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </templates:ItemsStack.ItemTemplate>
            </templates:ItemsStack>

          </ScrollView>
        </controls:PullToRefreshLayout> 

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Please take a look at the code after the mark "-- HERE! --".

**PS:** I'm just refining this layout on order to improve performance.

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand<string> btn_image_tap_preview
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand<string>(
            OpenImagePreview
        );
    }
}

//* Image tap
private async void OpenImagePreview(string url)
{
    //* Some code
}
```

Updated XAML:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="mainStack" Spacing="0">
        <commonViews:MainCustomNavBar MinimumHeightRequest="120" />
....
 <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
   <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference mainStack}, Path=BindingContext.btn_image_tap_preview}" 
                         CommandParameter="{Binding image_medium}" />
 </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
```

I'm debugging but I can't reach the ViewModel's command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `x:Reference` and take the binding context of any layout or element from your content page like StackLayout. Since its binding context is the ViewModel of the page it would have the command you are looking for at the first level itself. You can directly use it.

```
<StackLayout x:Name="myStackLayout" Spacing="0">
        <commonViews:MainCustomNavBar MinimumHeightRequest="120" />
....
 <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
   <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference myStackLayout}, Path=BindingContext.command_name}" 
                         CommandParameter="image_medium" />
 </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
```

Or you can set the binding context for TapGesture

```
<TapGestureRecognizer BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference myStackLayout.BindingContext}}" Command="{Binding command_name}"
```

`DataTemplates` does not seem to work well with `x:Reference` prior to v1.4.4, you can read more about in the forum post - [x:Reference not working?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33678/x-reference-not-working).
The implementation in the newer version can be seen in the answer [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/144204#Comment_144204).
If you are interested the Bugzilla issue that was fixed is [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=30684).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm trying with your solution but I can't make it work. I have updated my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have binding in your command parameter. It doesn't take binding.

Comment: I removed Binding but it's still not working, any other idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LuisdeHaro - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/144204#Comment_144204

Comment: When I profile using Source={x:Reference, I am seeing memory cycles. But I was having PageName as referenced. why does it cause memory leak?